# Live Charts with Highcharts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I am using [lazy_highcharts](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts) gem and trying to configure live charts.
Following this guide for [live charts](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use#live-charts) I have added a function in my controller that renders JSON output in this format `[1340051521000,8]`

```
def live
    x = Time.now.to_i * 1000
    y = Random.rand(11)
    #create an array and echo to JSON
    ret =[x,y]
    x=ActiveSupport::JSON
    @j=x.encode(ret)
    render :json => @j
  end
```

Next I have a new JS file called live_update.js where I pasted steps 2. and 3. containing 'requestData()'

I made the callback from the view:

```
 = high_chart("my_id", @h) do |c|
        requestData();
```

NOTE: I wasn't able to call it from my controller: `f.options[:chart][:events][:load] = 'requestData'`

When I run it, I get an error: chart is not defined, when clearly it was defined globally in the JS file.

This is what I see in the browser Source View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function() {
                  // 1. Define JSON options
                  var options = {
                                chart: {"defaultSeriesType":"column","renderTo":"my_id","zoomType":"xy"},
                                        title: {"text":"Test"},
                                        legend: {"layout":"horizontal","style":{}},
                                        xAxis: {"type":"datetime"},
                                        yAxis: {"title":{"text":"Agents"},"labels":{},"min":"0","allowDecimals":false,"gridLineDashStyle":"LongDash"},
                                        tooltip:  {"enabled":true},
                                        credits: {"enabled":false},
                                        plotOptions: {"areaspline":{}},
                                        series: [{"name":"test","data":[]}],
                                        subtitle: {}
                                };

                  // 2. Add callbacks (non-JSON compliant)                
                  requestData();


                  // 3. Build the chart
                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
              });
              </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works in version 1.1.6

```
f.options[:chart][:events] = {
  :load => %| function requestData(){
    $.ajax({
      url:"live",
      success: function(a){
        var c=chart.series[0], d=c.data.length>20;
        chart.series[0].addPoint(a,true,d);
        setTimeout(requestData,16e3)
      }, cache:false
    })
  }|.js_code
}
```